# Can I restrict a function to a specific constructor in a datatype?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a function like this:

```hs
myFunction :: Maybe a -> b
```

But it doesn't make any sense to call it with `Nothing` -- `Just a` are the only kind of values that make sense. Is it possible to represent this constraint in the type definition for `myFunction`?

I know I can always do the following, but it doesn't seem very clean to me:

```hs
myFunction Nothing = undefined
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question to completely change it's sense, you should have accepted the qualified answer you've already received for your original question and asked another one in a new thread. Please kindly do so. You'll find your updated question in the edit history. In the meantime I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 5):

> But it doesn't make any sense to call it with Nothing -- Just a are the only kind of values that make sense

It means that your looking for `myFunction :: a -> b`.

By the way, function that could map only specific set of a type values to something else is not total. If you use them, you always risk to end up with an `undefined`. In this particular case it looks like a redundant lack of purity.

Also, there is a partial function [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromJust) that could convert `Maybe a` to `a` and thrown exception for `Nothing`. And `myFunction . fromJust` is `:: Maybe a -> b`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I think I picked a really bad a example: The actual problem I have is not with "Maybe", it's with a custom datatype. I'll rephrase the question. Apologies for that!

Comment: So you want to have a function like `myFunction :: Just a -> b` and check in compile time that it is used only with `Just` values somehow? Don't think it is possible in the current universe

Comment: Use `fmap` instead of `fromJust`: `fmap (myFunction :: a -> b) :: Maybe a -> Maybe b`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez yep, `fromJust` here is just to satisfy the requested `:: Maybe a -> b` signature which is obviously unsafe